# Commerce line item fields - getting value

Tags: commerce

I have a custom line item type that has a List(Text) field. When I do this:

```
$line_item = commerce_line_item_load($lid);
```

I get an object that contains the value, but not the label of the selected option.

```
$line_item->field_ring_size[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] // returns 2 instead of, say, Large
```

How can I get the value's label instead?

I've tried using field_info_instance to get all values, as follows:

```
$info = field_info_instance('commerce_line_item', 'field_ring_size', 'ring_setting');
```

...but this does not return the values as far as I can see. Similarly, I've tried field_get_items, but this gives me the key back again.

How can I get the value (or a list of all values) instead of the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [list_allowed_values](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!list!list.module/function/list_allowed_values/7) function

```
  $field = field_info_field('field_name');
  $allowed_values = list_allowed_values($field);
```